# can OSPF LSR packet carry multiple LSA bodies for link efficiency?

Tags: cisco, ospf

can OSPF LSR packet carry multiple LSA bodies for link efficiency?

I know that "an OSPF LSU packet can carry multiple LSA bodies for link efficiency up to interface MTU (including IP and OSPF headers)" is that true about the LSR too? how could I check that?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

yes, LSR can also carry multiple LSA bodies, in this case LSA summaries.
use **debug ip ospf packet *detail***

Comment: thank you Praveen,this question is almost old,I've found the answer and yes that's right,I used Wireshark to get answer,I believe u mean "debug ip packet detail" command coz theres no "debug ip ospf packet detail" at least I did find nothing,thanks.